# Unit testing service calls from an Angular component rxjs subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I have this Angular (v13) code in a component:

```
export class MyComp {
  destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  submits$ = new Subject<MyFormState>(); // .next() in the template

  ngOnInit(){
    this.submits$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(formState => this.service.doSomething(formState));
  }
}
```

and I am trying to unit test it using jasmine spy object:

```
describe('MyComp', () => {
  let submits$ = new Subject<MyFormState>();
  let mock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', [ 'doSomething' ]);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComp ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useValue: mock },
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should be called when clicking the button', () => {
    const f: MyFormState = { name: 'my name' };
    component.submits$.next(formState);

    waitForAsync(() => {
      expect(mock.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith(f); // <-- false positives, anything passes
    });
  });
});
```

I have also tried another async pattern

```
it('should be called when clicking the button', fakeAsync(() => {
  // ...nexting

  tick();

  // without waitForAsync
  expect(mock.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith(f);
}));
```

but in this case the method never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?
What would be the correct way of testing this code without using `done()`?
Is it possible to use TestScheduler with this sort of anonymous subscription?

Comment: Fake async is for intervals and timeouts not observables

Comment: Would you mind giving an example template of how you're calling .next?

Comment: @WesleyTrantham `(myClick)="submits$.next(form.value)`

Comment: @AdrianBrand It doesn't seem so https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-fakeasync

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to call `fixture.detectChanges` to get this to work.

```
it('should be called when clicking the button', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges(); // the first call starts the lifecycle hook

  const formState: MyFormState = { name: 'my name' };
  component.submits$.next(formState);

  expect(mock.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith(formState); 

});
```

Now to tell you why this makes it work. The component as you are testing it includes the dom. Since you set up your subscription in the ngOnInit, the ngOnInit needs to execute to set that up.

With TestBed, ngOnInit isn't called until the first `fixture.detectChanges()` is called.

I know you haven't asked for this next part - my suggestion is to test your component by interacting with the html. That will provide you much better unit tests. [This book](https://testing-angular.com/) has been the closest to what my approach is.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work - I have `fitxure.detectChanges()` in `beforeEach` in this suite - even with this in place, anything satisfies `toHaveBeelCalledWith()`

Comment: Next step I would take is to fit that test, run it, and open the debugger in the browser that comes up. You can set a breakpoint and verify you aren't getting console errors on something. If you update the example I can take a look - I was able to get this working locally so you shouldn't be too far off. @user776686